# jQuery Form validation and submission issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, jquery-plugins

I have the following form that uses jQuery to validate a form and submit if all the fields are filled properly. Till now everything is working fine. But I want to add the following but not getting how to do so (as i am new to jQuery).

1. Text boxes (like first name & last name) should not accept any number.

How can I add these to my code? Please help.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
include'includes/db.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
     $fname =(!empty($_POST['firstname']))?$_POST['firstname']:null;
     $lname =(!empty($_POST['lastname']))?$_POST['lastname']:null;
     $email =(!empty($_POST['email']))?$_POST['email']:null;
     $mobile =(!empty($_POST['mobile']))?$_POST['mobile']:null;
     $dob =(!empty($_POST['dob']))?$_POST['dob']:null;
     $location =(!empty($_POST['location']))?$_POST['location']:null;
     $state =(!empty($_POST['state']))?$_POST['state']:null;
     $gender =(!empty($_POST['gender']))?$_POST['gender']:null;

     $str = "INSERT INTO members(mem_fname, mem_lname, mem_email, mem_mobile, mem_dob, mem_location, mem_state, mem_gender)VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$mobile', '$dob', '$location', '$state', '$gender')";
     $sql = mysql_query($str);

     if($sql){
     echo "Data Inserted Successfully";
     }else{
     echo "Data insertion failed";
     }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
  $(function() {
   $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
    });
    $("#register-form").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            mobile: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10,

            },
            dob: "required",
            location: "required",
            state: "required",
            gender: "required",
            agree: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your first name",
            lastname: "Please enter your last name",
            mobile: {
                required: "Please provide your mobile number",
                minlength: "Your mobile number must be 10 characters long"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            dob: "Please provide you Date of Birth",
            location: "Please provide your location",
            state: "Please provide your state",
            gender: "Please provide your gender",
            agree: "Please accept our terms of service"
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br />
<br />
<form action="" method="post" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="label">First Name</div>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
  <br />
  <div class="label">Last Name</div>
  <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" />
  <br />
  <div class="label">Email</div>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
  <br />
  <div class="label">Mobile</div>
  <input type="number" name="mobile" id="mobile" />
  <br />
  <div class="label">DOB</div>
  <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" class="datepicker"/>
  <br />
  <div class="label">Location</div>
  <input type="text" name="location" id="location" />
  <br />
  <div class="label">State</div>
  <input type="text" name="state" id="state" />
  <br />
  <div class="label">Gender</div>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male" />
  Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female" />
  Female<br />
  <div>
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="mobile" />
  &nbsp;Do You accept our terms of service?<br />
  <br />
  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read about regex in jquery/js here. http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-basic-regex-selector-examples/

Comment: You can use Regex for that.

Comment: I see you're using the `jquery.validate.min.js` plugin. You just have to use it... (Read its doc :)

Comment: could u please demonstrate using my code? @Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pattern rule from the additional-method.js file from jquery-validate

```
$("#register-form").validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: "required",
        lastname: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        mobile: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,
            pattern: /^[789]/
        },
        dob: "required",
        location: "required",
        state: "required",
        gender: "required",
        agree: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        firstname: "Please enter your first name",
        lastname: "Please enter your last name",
        mobile: {
            required: "Please provide your mobile number",
            minlength: "Your mobile number must be 10 characters long",
            pattern: 'should start with 7,8 or 9'
        },
        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        dob: "Please provide you Date of Birth",
        location: "Please provide your location",
        state: "Please provide your state",
        gender: "Please provide your gender",
        agree: "Please accept our terms of service"
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6jsshw17/)

Comment: You need to add `<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/additional-methods.js"></script>`

Comment: @ShubhamJha look at the fiddle, it is working there... so there is some other problem in your side... check your browser console to see whether there are any error

Comment: is it becoz of these?
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> Should I remove any of these?

Comment: did you add `<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/additional-methods.js"></scri‌​pt>`

Comment: yes i did.. but after adding this its submitting the form and validation is not working.. why?

Comment: but what about entering only alphabets in text field?

Comment: there too you can use a pattern like `pattern: /^[a-z]*$/i`

Comment: should i use the same word pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add new methods like this one:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkMobileNumberFirst", function(value, element) {
    firstNumber = value.substring(0,1);

    if (firstNumber <= 9 && firstNumber >=7  ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}, "The Mobile phone number has to start with 7, 8 or 9");
```

and then add the new method in your validation:

```
        mobile: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,      
            checkMobileNumberFirst: true
          },
```

Comment: I am new to jquery. How should I place this in my code.. could u please re edit and show in my code as a whole?

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryvalidation.org/ this link. it contains jquery validation plugin and demonstration ..